# How do I pass data up from the child page to the page calling @Body?

Tags: asp.net, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

So I have a MainLayout with a title bar, and I want to have a parameter that allows the page to set the title bar to whatever it wants. So mainlayout calls the page through @Body, I'm confused how I would pass data up through body to the mainlayout to update the title bar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="sidebar">
<NavMenu />
</div>
<div class="main">
<div class="top-row px-4">
    <h3 bind="@TitleValue">@(TitleValue)</h3>
    <a class="ml-md-auto">@ADService.LoggedUser().DisplayName (@*@(ADService.LoggedUser().IsMemberOf())*@Admin)</a>
</div>
<CascadingValue Value="@TitleValue" Name="TitleValue">
    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</CascadingValue>
</div>

<Footer />

@functions {
    string TitleValue = "Inventory";
}
```

So what I want to do is pass the TitleValue down, have the page update it depending what is happening and have the title bar update with the new value.

If this isn't the way to do it, or I'm missing something, any help would be great :)

Comment: In my opinion, they are not an elegant solution. Take a look to this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/857#issuecomment-390932846

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the following, **which is not mine**, can help you:

> Create a class which holds your data. Register it as singleton
>   service. Inject it into layout and into page. You should probably add
>   a notification mechanism to inform all your components that something
>   was changed in your data class.

[You can look here...](https://github.com/aspnet/samples/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/blazor/FlightFinder)

[Source and more...](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7641#issuecomment-464369466)

Comment: This actually worked really well. Can't believe I didn't think of it. Creating an "AppState" worked awesomely. The only thing I did was do a Transient instead because now it works like a sessionState which is even better for my use. Thank you!